# Can I get number inside square?

Tags: javascript

What I would like is when I click the demo button, it alerts me with number inside the green (selected) square.

```
$('#demo').click(function() {
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('selected');
var numb = x[0].innerHTML;
alert(numb);
});
```

Problem is currently I always get "1" as results, and this is not what is expected...

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Maybe because you are always accessing the first elment in your array of elements. This: `x[0].innerHTML`. The hard-coded 0

Comment: When do you ever get a green square? I can scroll to Moscow, all stay blue.

Comment: Pick either JavaScript or jQuery... You're using both and it's not needed. You're making your life harder than it should be. You use `document.getElementsByClassName("selected")` and then the index of the item when you can instead use `$(".selected:last")` or replace last with an index and make your life WAY easier...

Comment: The problem was you posted the link with a protocol of https. Using https on jsfiddle prevents loading jQuery or any other library since they are served from different domains. If the browser you have been using doesn't prevent that, I strongly recommend switching to a more secure browser **now**!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to access the last element than accessing first element. Also add selected class to first element by default:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
  var numb = $('.selected:last').text();
  alert(numb);
});
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/k6o9jj1q/)**

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are only **removing** the class of `selected` when you scroll **up** past it, otherwise it will keep the class.

*When using JavaScript Console*

```
document.getElementsByClassName('selected');

[<li class=​"post selected">​1​</li>​, 
 <li class=​"post selected">​2​</li>​, 
 <li class=​"post selected">​3​</li>​, 
 <li class=​"post selected">​4​</li>​, 
 <li class=​"post selected">​5​</li>​]
```

You need to either fix the logic to remove all the other `selected` classes when a new one is added.

Or you can just select the last selected as I have done in the following example by using `x.length - 1`

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('selected');
var numb = x[x.length - 1].innerHTML;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f3wqznek/1/

Comment: I'm sorry I can't accept more than one answer but this helps me a lot and answers my question too ! Thank you very much, @UsainBloot

Comment: Doesn't matter, was just generally interested in scrolling js you provided! I would suggest sticking with either vanilla JavaScript or JQuery instead of a hybrid of both. Just makes things a bit easier.

Answer (score 0):

## You get what you ask for.

When you scroll, you add a class `.selected` to every `li` that leaves the viewport. So when you do `document.getElementsByClassName('selected')` you get an array of DOM objects of which you always access the *first*. Instead, access the **last**:

```
var x= document.getElementsByClassName('selected');
var numb = x[x.length-1].innerHTML;
```